# Ubuntu 22.04 Scroll Lock button (light) doesn't work

Tags: 22.04, shortcut-keys

After upgrading to 22.04, the <kbd>Scroll</kbd> <kbd>Lock</kbd> button (keyboard light) doesn't work. I was using:

```
xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'
```

but this doesn't work in this release.

Any fix?

Comment: xmodmap is, as the name suggests, for Xorg. You are running Wayland now.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 22.04 the following command still works for me:

```
xset led named "Scroll Lock"
```

Tested on

```
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS | OS Type 64 Bit | Gnome Version 42.4 | Windowing System X11
```

Answer (score 0):

If uses based on Ubuntu and Wayland needs install lib from ubuntu

```sh
sudo apt install light
```

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/light.1.html

```sh
light -L # to list all devices with scrolllock
```

and try based on input{NUMBER}::scrolllock (need see item with scrolllock)

```sh
# to activate
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/input11::scrolllock/brightness'
```

```
# to deactivate
sudo sh -c 'echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/input11::scrolllock/brightness'
```

*input 11 works for me, because this is my scrolllock, but need see your scrolls for activate or not*